# What are the names of the endpoints provided by the Django auth app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

What are the **names** of the endpoints provided by the Django auth model?  E.g., if I want to link to the login page, what do I put in the template?

```
<a href={% url ???? %}>Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Real Python article on [getting started with Django user management](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/) provides a nice list about half way down:

| Path | Name | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `accounts/login/` | `login` | User login form |
| `accounts/logout/` | `logout` | User logout form |
| `accounts/password_chage/` | `password_change` | Change password form |
| `accounts/password_change/done` | `password_change_done` | Confirmation page |
|  |  |  |
| `accounts/password_reset` | `password_reset` | For sending a password reset link to the account email |
| `accounts/password_reset/done/` | `password_reset_done` | Confirmation page that email is sent |
| `accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/` | `password_reset_confirm` | Endpoint used to reset the password from the email link |
| `accounts/reset/done/` | `password_reset_complete` | Confirmation page |